# How does targeting work with spray fire?

Tags: frozen-synapse

I had a hard time thinking of a title for this one that briefly encompassed my question.

If my unit using a weapon with bullets (vs. explosives; I know rockets and grenades kill everything in their radius), can the bullets damage a unit that is not the target?  For example, if 2 enemies are in a line and I tell my unit to ignore one, can he still "accidentally" kill the ignored one?  If one of my units is in the line of fire, either blocking the enemy unit or behind it, will my friendly bullets kill him?

Comment: I haven't played much, but I did notice that a friendly shotgun blast appeared to do no damage to a comrade caught in the LOF. The hostile in between died a bloody death. Needs more testing to be sure, but I *think* there is not bullet-based FF...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only friendly fire in Frozen Synapse is from your own rockets/grenades.  Machine gunners and shotgunners cannot harm friendly units.  I'll look through my video logs for something to upload to youtube, but not sure if I have that exact scenario.

As for targeting one enemy and killing another (ie one behind him), I'm 99% sure you cannot kill another enemy unit with "stray" fire.  I have a match open and am playing the future turn with a unit directly behind another unit of mine under fire, and he is completely safe.  If the future turn ends up like that, I'll upload the video to youtube.

As of now, I don't have any video evidence of either, but will look for it/test for it.  But, I'm almost positive that aside from rockets/grenades, units will only kill the enemy unit that they are targeting, not any nearby units, whether they are friend or foe.

Comment: To support the second paragraph: Last night I played a defence match (I forget the proper game, but I'm new, oh well) where the other player had stacked all three units in exactly the same place. I managed to flank them and had a single machine gunner take down all three, one at a time, in three distinct bursts of gunfire - no collateral injuries.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the wiki](http://fs.error420.com/wiki/Principles_of_Combat), the kill shot is the only bullet that matters, the rest is just "eye candy" to show that the unit is engaged in combat.